# Is there a way to make a c# console application compatible with other pcs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, frameworks, console-application

I made a c# console program to do SMPT. I was checking if it works on other computers too, but when i tested i got this output from console - "It has not possible to find any compatible framework...".
Is there a way to make this application compatible with every framework? If not, are there other possibilities? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is the installed .Net version you can build the code for an other version or install the required .Net version on the other pc.
if you want to change the build target version
go to your project properties (to do so just right click your project and then properties).
and under "application" change the target framework